# Ruby Socket TCPServer send png image to client

Tags: ruby, image, sockets, httpserver, tcpserver

I have an http server using sockets that gets all client data, and sends back data. I am successfully able to send back HTML to the client (my web browser) but whenever I try and send an image, I get a small white square no matter what image I send.

The code:

```
#Generate and send response
def response(client, response = 200, headers, data)
    client.print "HTTP/1.1 #{response.to_s}\r\n"
    headers_s = ""
    for h in headers do
        headers_s = headers_s + h + "\n"
    end
    client.print "#{headers_s}\r\n"
    client.print "\r\n"
    client.print data.to_s
end

response(client, 200, ["Content-Type: image/png"], File.read("./very_cool_picture.png"))
```

I probably am reading the image wrong, but I am not sure. Also, sending back other binary data such as executables does not work properly either even with the correct headers.

There is also more code that I did not show because it was excessive and irrelevant that accepts the clients, parses requests, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra `\r\n` between the headers and the data. After each header you add a `\n` (should really be a `\r\n`), then when you print them out you add another (`client.print "#{headers_s}\r\n"`), and then finally you write out another. This extra two bytes is resulting in the browser seeing invalid PNG data.

Removing the line `client.print "\r\n"` should fix your issue.

(You should probably also send a Content-Length header, although it will still work without one.)

Comment: The Content-Length is part of the other code that I did not show, but it automatically does add that.